# Resolution and frame size for TV RAW processing

Tags: post-processing, remote, apple

I'm thinking about using my Vizio 55-inch 1080p LED TV for RAW processing. I would connect the MacBook to it via HDMI.

Considering that I would be standing about 2.5 meters away, which combination of resolution and size of the picture on TV would be best to work with?

Comment: I don't get why people answer questions that they don't vote up. Two answers and zero votes up.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things to note about LED TVs.  If it is edge lit, then the TV is going to have areas of relative brightness that will be inconsistent with the actual image and no amount of calibration will account for this.  If it is directly LED back lit then you should be ok using 1920 by 1080 resolution for a 1080p display.  You will also need to turn off a lot of the built in processing on the TV to get a suitable level of color quality for RAW processing.

Certainly calibration would be helpful, but an actual monitor, particularly a S-IPS monitor would likely yield far superior results to a TN LED backlit TV.

You can have the image at whatever size is convenient for you on the display as far as the ideal size to use.  Using a neutral grey background when doing your editing and having a fairly dark environment will also probably help with your color perception.

Answer (score 0):

An HD TV has one native resolution (1920x1080 for a 1080p or 1080i display). If you use anything lower than that, there will be upscaling, which, since it's a TV, will probably be optimized for video. Use the native resolution and scale in your photo software for better results.

Make sure to tweak the TV's display settings. Most that I've seen default to a very strong sharpening filter, which you almost certainly don't want. Ideally, use calibration hardware and software as you would with any monitor.

As for size, I don't think there can be any answer other than "whatever feels comfortable to you?"